# Script to refresh Dashboard on page load not working

Tags: javascript

I have a script which does not seem to be working. I can’t see error in the console as well. It seems that the on load itself is not working. Kindly suggest. Below is the script that I have written

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
    window.onload = function() { 
            alert('click');
            var dashboardButton = document.getElementById('db_ref_btn');
            alert('before click');
            dashboardButton.click();
            alert('after click');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where did you paste this script?

Comment: home page component > html area >

Comment: I have added the component on the home page layout as well

Comment: I found this at https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_home_page_components.htm
In Summer ’15 we will start removing unsupported code from HTML Area home page components. As a result, components that contain JavaScript, CSS, iframes, or other unsupported markup might stop working properly. To use JavaScript or other advanced HTML elements in your home page component, we recommend that you use a Visualforce Area component instead.

Comment: So you have added a VF component. Then you should check if you can access this might be getting CORS exception.

Comment: I tried with HTML area first and it gave error,then i tried with VF component and i am now getting CORS exception.So is this not possible now ?are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs which you have shared (last para)

> You can include JavaScript in your Visualforce page, but because the
>   component is rendered in an iframe on the home page layout, the
>   JavaScript can’t interact with the page that contains the component.

So I don't think this will work for you. You might be getting CORS exception.  As of now I don't think we have any other available option.

Comment: So not other alternative for this??

Comment: @Samir in my opinion No.

Comment: There's A Chrome Extension - 'enhanced salesforce dashboard' which can be served as a workaround: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhance-salesforce-dashbo/mogildlgjglckdcfclpbcbidpdkjgeeb